# discord bot failing to send direct message, upon kicking (discord.py)

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, bots

The code kicks the user, but it unable to send a DM

```
@bot.command()
    async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'oh no- {member.mention} has been kicked :/')
        message=f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name}"
        await member.send(message)
```

**While testing:**

1. The kicked users DMs were open
2. the bot had admin privileges

**The console gives out this error:**

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't DM a user if you aren't friends with him and don't have any mutal guilds. So you should try to first message the user then kick him. Also I would add a try/except statment for ``member.send`` so if you can't message the user, the whole command won't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to send the message before the actual kicking.

Otherwise, the bot can't handle the user.

So, send the message to the user and the kick him.

```
@bot.command()
    async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
        message=f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name}"
        await member.send(message)
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f'oh no- {member.mention} has been kicked :/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter FORBIDDEN if you attempt to direct message a user that has DMs disabled for non-friends.

Don't forget to handle the exception:

```
try:
  /* send message */
except Exception: 
  pass
```

Comment: Please use `except discord.Forbidden:` using a general exception is not recommended [Source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Forbidden)

Comment: It isnt showing an error, but the code still isnt working :/